# When I export a game the executable file hasn't got any textures

Tags: texturing, game-engine

I have a game with textures and I want to export the game into an executable file. I know how to export it but when I run it, it hasn't got any textures? Please help.

Comment: Are you using [these instructions](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/FAQ/Game_Engine/Standalone_game)?

Comment: Yes, I export using File>>Export>>Save as game engine runtime

Comment: Are you packing external data before you export, as per the instructions?

Comment: Yes, and the texture in the game turns black

Comment: Never used BGE, but have you tried to make all paths relative? (File->External Data)

Comment: Nop, i'll try now

Comment: I suggest to post suggestions as answer rather than as comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want your application file include the textures then you need to perform `Mainmenu/File/External Data/Pack All Into .blend` before creating the application file.

[image]

Each asset that is not included will not be found and therefore not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not want your application file to include external assets you need to perform `Mainmenu/File/External Data/Make All Paths Relative` before creating the application file.

[image]

Do not forget to deliver the files with the application file at the same relative position as at the moment of path change.

Each asset that is not found will not be displayed.

**Remarks:**

- You need to deliver with relative paths as the end-user will not use your local paths.
- It is easier to develop with absolute paths. This allows to move the  linking .blend file around without the need to adjust the paths.
- Moving linked .blend files around always requires to update the paths withing the linking .blend files regardless if the paths are relative or absolute.